# Disable Close Modal on Outside Click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, materialize

I am making some blog that use modal(s) with **Materializecss**, but i have problem with my modal onclick outside and on the false data, here is my code:

**main.js**

```
function changepassword(){
 var user = $('#userlog').val();
 var content  = ""; 

content += '<div id="modganpas" class="modal modal-fixed-footer">';
content += '<div class="modal-content">';
content += '<form>';        
content += '<style="text-align:center;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;"><h3>change Password</h3>';
content += '<div><i class="material-icons">supervisor_account</i>';             
content += '</div>';
content += '<div class="row">';
content += '<div class="input-field col s12">';
content += '<input id="changeUsername" name="changeUsername" type="text" class="validate" disabled>';
content += '</div>';
content += '<div class="input-field col s12">';
content += '<input id="changePasswordold" maxlength="32" name="changePasswordold" type="password" class="validate">';
content += '<label for="changePasswordold">Password old</label></div>';
content += '<div class="input-field col s6">';
content += '<input id="changePasswordnew" maxlength="32" name="changePasswordnew" type="password" class="validate">';
content += '<label for="changePasswordnew">Password new</label></div>';
content += '<div class="input-field col s6">';
content += '<input id="changePasswordnew1" maxlength="32" name="changePasswordnew1" type="password" class="validate">';
content += '<label for="changePasswordnew1">Ulangi Password</label></div>';
content += '</div>';
content += '</form>';
content += '</div>';
content += '<div class="modal-footer">';
content += '<a href="#" onClick="check_ganpass()" id="btn_ok" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat ">Edit</a>';
content += '<a href="#!" onClick="cancelchangePassword()" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-red btn-flat ">Cancel</a>';
content += '</div>';
content += '</div>';
content += '</div>';

        $("#formodal").append(content);
        $('#changeUsername').val(user);}


//for check


    function check_ganpass(){
    var username = $('#changeUsername').val();
    var passwordold = $('#changePasswordold').val();
    var passwordnew = $('#changePasswordnew').val();
    var passwordnew1 = $('#changePasswordnew1').val();
    var urlnyah    = 'pas.php';

    $.ajax({
        url     : urlnyah,


        data    : 'username='+username+'&passwordold='+passwordold+'&passwordnew='+passwordnew+'&passwordnew1='+passwordnew1, 
        type    : 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        success : function(pesan){
            if(pesan=='ok,'){
                Materialize.toast('Data Telah Berubah',4000);
            }
            else{
                Materialize.toast(pesan,4000);
            }
        }
    });}
```

**pas.php**

```
<?php include("connection.php");
session_start();
$username = $_POST['username'];
$passwordold = md5($_POST['passwordold']);
$passwordnew = md5($_POST['passwordnew']);
$passwordnew1 = md5($_POST['passwordnew1']);
    $query = mysql_query("select * from tuser where username ='$username' and password = '$passwordold'");
    $data = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if ($data ==1)
    {   if ($passwordnew == $passwordnew1){     mysql_query("UPDATE tuser SET password='$passwordnew1' WHERE username='$username'");
            echo "ok,";
        } else {
        echo "Password new not same";
        }}else{
        echo "Password old werong.";}?>
```

**connection.php**

```
<?php $sambung=mysql_connect('localhost','root', '')or die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("test", $sambung)or die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());?>
```

The question is how to disable closing the modal on click outside of the box and if the entered data is wrong.

Thanks for the correction.

Comment: you can also write custom code to hide the modal.

Comment: talk is cheap show me the code, and please i use materialize.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

// for disable modal when click outside

```
$('#modalid').openModal({dismissible:false});
```

// remove modal-action modal-close in ok button

```
<a href="#" onClick="check_ganpass()" id="btn_ok" class="waves-effect waves-green btn-flat ">Edit</a>
```

// insert bellow "Materialize.toast('Data Telah Berubah',4000);"

```
$('modalid').closeModal();
```

hope that answer your question. :)

Answer (score 3):

if you have only one modal, and are using jquery, you can do :

```
$('#myModal').modal()[0].M_Modal.options.dismissible = false;
$('#myModal').modal('open');
```

cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#ModalID').modal({
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false
})
```

or in html set data attributes as below

```
data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"
```

on popup call

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

You can use **dismissible**  Option for preventing this

```
 $('#your_modal_ID').modal({
                dismissible: false
            })
```